# SQL Aggregate Transactions by detail & Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to aggregate the total amounts of certain items. For example, I want to get the total amount for all transactions that have a trx_desc of "Amazon" and were in the month of August, for example.

This is the query that I used to try and output this data:

```
select det_trx_type, SUM(amount) as 'Total Amt',
CASE
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 8 THEN 'August'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 9 THEN 'September'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 10 THEN 'October'
END
as 'Month'

from av_finance 
where det_trx_type IN(
select distinct det_trx_type from av_finance)
group by  posting_date, det_trx_type
```

Data from query

[image]

I would like the total of Amazon purchases in the Month of August to show up on 1 row rather than multiple rows for each purchase in a given month.

Comment: Stop grouping by posting_date, group by the CASE expression too (or derive that in a CTE or subquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to let `CASE WHEN` in group by instead of only `posting_date` column because `posting_date` seems to be date data type.

```
select det_trx_type, SUM(amount) as 'Total Amt',
CASE
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 8 THEN 'August'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 9 THEN 'September'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 10 THEN 'October'
END as 'Month'
from av_finance 
where det_trx_type IN(select distinct det_trx_type from av_finance)
group by  
CASE
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 8 THEN 'August'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 9 THEN 'September'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 10 THEN 'October'
END, det_trx_type
```

Comment: What is the purpos of `where det_trx_type IN...`?

Comment: @Sami My intention was to get only the distinct (only 1 of each) transaction types (det_trx_type). In hopes that the output would limit the rows to have only 1 of each transaction types rather than multiple. My logic was flawed. I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to aggregate in this way:

```
select det_trx_type, SUM(amount) as 'Total Amt',
    CASE
        when MONTH(posting_date) = 8 THEN 'August'
        when MONTH(posting_date) = 9 THEN 'September'
        when MONTH(posting_date) = 10 THEN 'October'
    END
    as 'Month'

    from av_finance 
    where det_trx_type IN(
    select distinct det_trx_type from av_finance)
    group by  MONTH(posting_date), det_trx_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop grouping by `posting_date`, group by the CASE expression too (or derive that in a CTE or subquery). Here is a CTE example:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  select det_trx_type, amount,
  CASE
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 8 THEN 'August'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 9 THEN 'September'
    when MONTH(posting_date) = 10 THEN 'October'
  END as [Month] -- don't use ' for aliases!
  from dbo.av_finance  -- always use schema!
)
SELECT [Month], det_trx_type, SUM(amount)
FROM x
GROUP BY [Month], det_trx_type;
```

Also I removed the `where in`...`distinct` clause. I'm not sure what purpose it served.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. When you say "don't use ' for aliases, always use schema" what is an example of the schema you used in your query. Is it the ;WITH x as...?

Comment: `'` for aliases is deprecated in certain forms (see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)) and can easily be misinterpreted as a string literal. The schema I'm talking about is the container for objects. See [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [this post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-semi-colons-schema-prefix/).